# How to bind data between parent-child components

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, vuejs2

I have a simple Form component with just a select option. Whenever I choose an option, a child component is rendered inside my main component. My problem is I can't get Vue to bind my parent component data with child component data.

`form.settings` is dynamic so I can not set the properties before hand at `Form.vue`.

This form is submitted to a Spring-boot web application via axios and I see that `form.settings` is null on client side when I submit the form.

I am new to Vue and here is my attempt:

Form.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <form>
      <div>
        <select v-model="form.type">
          <option></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <PresetOne v-if="form.type == '1'" :settings="form.settings"/>
      <PresetTwo v-if="form.type == '2'" :settings="form.settings"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PresetOne from "@/components/PresetOne"
import PresetTwo from "@/components/PresetTwo"

export default {
  name: "SettingsForm",
  data: () => ({
    form: {
      type: null,
      settings: null
    }
  }),
  components: {
    PresetOne,
    PresetTwo
  }
}
</script>
```

PresetOne.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="settings.username" />
    <input v-model="settings.password" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "PresetOne",
  data: () => ({
    settings: {
      username: null,
      password: null
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

PresetTwo.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="settings.email" />
    <input v-model="settings.password" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "PresetTwo",
  data: () => ({
    settings: {
      email: null,
      password: null
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what are you doing in the child components is changing the Data state of that component only, that's the reason why you couldn't bind that to the parent.

Try this:

*PresetOne.vue & PresetTwo.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="settings.email" />
    <input v-model="settings.password" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['settings']
}
</script>
```

Update: remember to set `settings`'s default value in form.vue to be an empty object so you can be able to assign the properties from the child components.

Comment: This causes error. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null`. Probably because `settings` object have no keys defined right now.

Comment: Yes! that was the reason for the error, a fast solution is to set the `settings` value to be empty object, like this:  `settings: {}` in form.vue

Comment: What I ended up doing is define every possible key for `settings` object in parent and bind them via `props`. Your answer has led me to a solution so I accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can send data to child components as properties

```
<PresetOne v-if="form.type == '1'" :settings="form.settings"/>
```

To use the property in child component, you need to receive the property like

```
export default {
  name: "PresetOne",
  props:["settings"]
}
```

You can also communicate from child component to parent component using the `$emit()` option.

Reference : [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#props), [emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event)

Also, you can use your data section as follows:

```
data:()=>{
  return {
    // add your variables here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-shadow-g8sri), this might be helpful.

Basically, `form.settings` that you're sending is null which is not even being used in the child component. So, no where `form.settings` is being updated.